# how to integrate with docusign and php

Tags: php, docusignapi

i am very new to this trying to integrate docusign with php i am using following code

```
$integratorKey = 'XXXX';
$email = 'mageshkumar.it@gmail.com';
$password = 'XXXX';
$name = "mageshkumar";
// copy the templateId of an existing template here
$templateId = "C9D9D181-CE57-.....................";
// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";
```

only one thing i want this is get the status update of the recived file.

Comment: so what is the error you got?

Comment: error calling webservice, status is:0 this the error i am getting,i just i need to fetch this information (Get Status and Docs)

Comment: I don't see any webservice calls in your code

Comment: agreed- no webservice call in the referenced call, and not a very clear question.  Please improve.

Answer (score 0):

This code is definitely not complete and also some basic error checking has not been done.  Obviously calling webservice is not working but it might be on a very low level.  For instance your firewall could be the problem and it has nothing to do with DocuSign web service.  I suggest you go to www.docusign.com/devcenter and try following the curl based examples from your machine.  Maybe then try pinging a public website from PHP.  This is all just connectivity 101.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into setting up a callback URL, and keep track of envelopes in your own database. I don't have an example link for you, maybe @ergin or @mikebz can post one.

Otherwise, have a look here at the PHP API Service examples:

https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/blob/master/PHP/CodeSnippets/ApiServiceSnippets.php